# securing host using ssl certificate and using azure kubernetes ingress yaml

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have obtained a ssl certificate from godaddy which had two files in it `generated-csr.txt` and `generated-private-key.txt`.

By using these two files i created a secret `my-tls-secret` using these two commands

```
$ cat generated-csr.txt generated-private-key.txt | base64 > my-secret.txt 

$ kubectl create secret generic my-secret –from-file=my-secret.txt
```

Then i pointed this secret in my azure kubernetes ingress file the contents of files are these:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: default
  uid: f6cb8431-a03e-4484-9921-cb7d71c3bfba
  resourceVersion: '293356'
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '2023-05-08T08:45:00Z'
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  managedFields:
    - manager: Mozilla
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      time: '2023-05-08T08:45:00Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {}
        f:spec:
          f:rules: {}
          f:tls: {}
    - manager: nginx-ingress-controller
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      time: '2023-05-08T08:45:45Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:status:
          f:loadBalancer:
            f:ingress: {}
      subresource: status
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - d.example.in
      secretName: my-tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: d.example.in
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: d-frontend
                port:
                  name: http
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: ipaddress
```

but after this procedures my host which is "d.example.in" is still not secured . how can i secure my host and i have purchased my certificate from godaddy.

I was expecting to secure my host using the secret which was created by using SSL certificate

Comment: What do you mean “ it’s not secured”? That is still accesible through http?

Comment: yes it is accesible through http but not through https. I want my host to be secured through https

Comment: Take a look at my edit !

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: So after I formatted your question I was able to better understand your problem(s).

1. You got a CSR and Key. The CSR is what you use to get an actual certificate from the certification authority. You need to get an actual certificate, the CSR is not.
2. a TLS secret on kubernetes is created with a specific command

Note the "tls" after secret:

```
kubectl create secret tls test-tls --key="tls.key" --cert="tls.crt"
```

So first you need a CRT not a CSR and then you could try this.

But there are better ways of getting a certificate for your domain using kubernetes, I'd say the industry standard is to use [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/).

This is a quite detailed [guide on the topic](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-site-in-kubernetes-with-cert-manager-traefik-and-let-s-encrypt), using Let's Encrypt to get a free certificate for your domain that is renewed automatically.

Comment: Tried this but its still not working. Thank you

Comment: Got 3 files from godaddy two .crt files and one .pem file. Now i have created a secret usin g these files and used that secret in ingress yaml file but still my website is not secured and it is not running on HTTPS